# How to made custom Split array function in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

How to make a custom made function Split(str as String, delimiter as String ) using Split() in VBA to be used in worksheet.. and it will return as array or SPILL the result..
For example,

```
Split("{20;30;40;50;60}",";")
```

will return Spill down Array result in the same array as in the written formula as:

```
20
30
40
50
60
```

I try to use the Split(String,";") in VBA function but it only return 1 value and in text type..
I also need to remove both ' { ' and ' } ' in the string if there but accept it even if it is no there..

Comment: show the whole udf that you tried.

Comment: You need to show your function line.  I would bet that the error lays there.

Comment: Try this: `Application.Worksheets("YourWorksheet").Range("A1:A5") = Application.Transpose(Split(Replace(Replace("{20;30;40;50;60}", "{", ""), "}", ""), ";"))`

Comment: @GWD if the OP has Office 365 all that is unnecessary and cannot be done with a UDF.

Comment: @GWD I am waiting for the OP to show theirs, so I can teach and not give the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not call your function `Split`
2. Use Nested `Replace`
3. We need to return a `String` array.

---

```
Function mysplit(str As String, deli As String) As String()
    mysplit = split(Replace(Replace(str, "{", ""), "}", ""), deli)
End Function
```

Then I would call it like this:

```
=LET(x,mySplit("{20;30;40;50;60}",";"),IF(ISNUMBER(--x),--x,x))
```

[image]

If you want it transposed then use `TRANSPOSE`

```
=LET(x,mySplit("{20;30;40;50;60}",";"),TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(--x),--x,x)))
```

[image]

---

A single formula can do it all without the need of vba:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("{20;30;40;50;60}",";","</b><b>"),"}",""),"{","")&"</b></a>","//b")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. I am not good at VBA.. I try to search solution but cannot quite understand.. out of frustration I deleted the file.. I think I prefer the single formula without VBA.. and does FilterXML really need that a and b tag? What does that mean?

Comment: `FilterXM()`L needs a *wellformed* XML structure (comparable in some way with a html structure) with at least a `documentElement` *on top*, here e.g. `<a>...</a>` and additionally subnodes (e.g. `<b>..</b>`) therein to identify your array items :-)

Answer (score 3):

The UDF should use a **two dimensional array**:

```
Public Function splitt(s As String, sep As String)
    arr = Split(s, sep)
    
    ReDim arr2(0 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr2(i, 1) = arr(i)
    Next i
    
    splitt = arr2
End Function
```

Example:

[image]

With **Excel 365** ,  it will auto-spill.  Without **Excel 365**, it will need array-entry.